# android.webkit.PermissionRequest can't be resolved

Tags: java, android, permissions, webkit, webchromeclient

I want to override the [`public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onPermissionRequest%28android.webkit.PermissionRequest%29) method for my `WebChromeClient`-object.

Here is my code:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
        CallActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //TODO: do sth with the request
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried to import [`android.webkit.PermissionRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest.html), but it can't be resolved.
Am I missing a library?

Comment: It's only  **Added in API level 21**

Comment: @tynn - I want to run the app on a google glass. How do I find out which android version is installed?

Comment: Is it a runtime or build problem?

Comment: @tynn - A build problem. Eclipse can't resolve the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only **Added in API level 21** so you need to make sure to build your project with Android 21 or later.

Considering you're building for Google Glass, you're not able to use it at runtime. As far as I know Google Glass is running on Android 19 only.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to use the webView with getUserMedia() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) Can I do this without the permission/ WebChromeClient?

Comment: @RUB3N I don't know. I had a look for how it was done before, but couldn't find anything. I guess you might just need to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As [tynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385212/tynn) pointed out, this is currently not possible, since Glass runs on **API level 19**, but **API level 21** [is required for **getUserMedia**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream).

However the guys over at Ericsson Research figured it out as you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/N6fQNjMKuKI).

They used [OpenWebRTC](http://www.openwebrtc.org/).

Find out more about implementing it [here](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples/wiki/Developing-Android-apps).